# Running Shell script from within Python issue

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

So, I am trying to run a Shell script from Python and I double checked that the location of the `script.sh` is all correct (because when I run it from sublime, the `script.sh` opens). What I have to call `script.sh` is:

`subprocess.call("script.sh", shell=True)`

When I run that, the function returns 0. However, the script is supposed to create a file in my folder and write into it, which it is not doing. It does work when I run the script from cygwin command prompt.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What's in the script?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure you have added:

`!/bin/bash`

as the first line and also make sure that the file script.sh has executable permission.

`chmod u+x script.sh`

then try specifying the complete path:

`subprocess.call("/complete/path/script.sh", shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your shell script somewhere, put the line:

```
pwd >/tmp/mytempfile
```

and then run the Python script and go look into that file.

This will let you find out the working directory of your scripts which, in the majority of cases where a file doesn't appear to be created, is different to what you think it should be.

You may also want to check the shell script to ensure it's not *changing* the working directory before creating the file but that would be unlikely given you've stated it works okay from the command line.

If you add the line to create the temporary file and it doesn't actually get created, then your script is not executing.

In that case, you could try a few things. The *first* is to fully specify the script on the off chance that Python isn't in the correct directory. In other words, something like:

```
subprocess.call("/actual/path/to/script.sh", shell=True)
```

Or you could try to run the actual `bash` executable with the script as an argument:

```
subprocess.call("bash -c script.sh", shell=True)
```

Comment: I did that at the top of the shell script but it does not create a tmp folder or tempfile..

Comment: @bycfly: well, now you know it's not actually running, at least. I'll add some more options based on that.